# Remove $watch and bring the logic out of the $watch in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have a code in AngularJS which looks like below :

```
$scope.startWatching = function () {
    return $scope.$watch('form', function (n, o) {
        var timeoutPromise;

        $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);  //does nothing, if timeout alrdy done
        timeoutPromise = $timeout(function () {
            if (n !== o) {
                if ($scope.isLegacy) {
                    $scope.showCompleteBtn = $scope.showCompleteButton2();
                } else {
                    $scope.showCompleteBtn = $scope.showCompleteButton();
                }
            }
        }, 400);



    }, true);
```

So whenever form changes, either $scope.showCompleteButton2() is called or $scope.showCompleteButton() is called.

The problem is that the $watch() gets called many number if times, so I need to bring these two methods out of the $watch().

Comment: It might help if you describe, in detail, exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish. It's hard to suggest an alternative without knowing this.

Comment: Please tell me what more you want , i can edit the question. I want to remove this $watch function and take out the logic inside it

Comment: Specifically what is changing on the form that you want to trigger this off of? You should probably be using `ng-change` directives instead of a `$watch()` on the form itself.

Comment: The watch has been placed on the form because the controls dynamically appear inside a div which is in the form. Hence do you think ng-change will work ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Watchers like event listeners should only be added once when the DOM is built. And removed when the DOM is torn down.

If the code needs to enable or disable the actions performed by the watcher, provide a state in the model to do so:

```
var enableWatch = false;

$scope.startWatching = function () {
    enableWatch = true;
};

var timeoutPromise;

$scope.$watch('form', function (n, o) {
    if (!enableWatch) return;

    //ELSE
    timeoutPromise && $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
    timeoutPromise = $timeout(function () {
        if (n !== o) {
            if ($scope.isLegacy) {
                $scope.showCompleteBtn = $scope.showCompleteButton2();
            } else {
                $scope.showCompleteBtn = $scope.showCompleteButton();
            }
        }
    }, 400);

}, true);
```

The watcher ignores changes when the `enableWatch` variable is `false`. Set the variable to  `true` to enable the specified actions.

Comment: What is the need for having a `$timeout` inside of `$watch`? It sounds a bit pointless, unless I'm missing something

Comment: @AlonEitan Hard to tell what the function does at all without knowing what changes `$scope.form` and what the `$scope.showCompleteButton*` functions do, As written in the example, everytime the `$scope.startWatching` function is invoked the code adds an additional watcher. This answer shows how to avoid added those extra watchers.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg , i made changes as per your suggestion and i am able to get to it.

Comment: You can safely unbind $watch statements in AngularJS. When you call $scope.$watch(...), a function that can be used to unbind the $watch is returned. To get the unbind function, do something like `var watchHandle = $scope.$watch(...);`. To unbind the watch with your unbind function, do `watchHandle();` and the watch will be removed.